# Soap endpoints not appearing in servicestack Asp.Net core application

Tags: servicestack

Newly created Asp.Net core application with ServiceStack.Core package does not expose Soap end point. It only expose Json endpoints as shown in the image below. Soap endpoint support are not supported for Asp.Net core project?

[API view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEXPY.png)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [SOAP Documentation](http://docs.servicestack.net/soap-support#configure) SOAP support requires the ASP.NET Framework.

Which can be enabled by registering the SoapFeature plugin:

```
Plugins.Add(new SoapFormat());
```

It requires WCF/SOAP Support that's only available in the classic ASP.NET Framework so it can only be enabled in the [ASP.NET Framework Templates](https://github.com/NetFrameworkTemplates) (i.e. not .NET Core).

Comment: To future moderators like [Samuel Liew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584192/samuel-liew) please do some research before pro-actively being hostile and deleting questions without merit (actions like are giving StackOverflow a bad name). If you're going to report a duplicate answer, include a link to the duplicate answer. My answer is a direct answer to this question, there is no duplicate answer. You especially shouldn't be deleting the only answer that directly answers the question.